# Modify semantic UI column

Tags: html, css, meteor, responsive-design, semantic-ui

I have a question, is it possible to modify the width of a 'div class=column' in semantic? I have a two column grid container, but I would wish that one column to have 70% width and the other one 30%. Semantic makes bot columns with equal width 50%.

Comment: not meteor related.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<div class="ui grid">
  <div class="five wide column"></div>
  <div class="eleven wide column"></div>
</div>
```

see https://semantic-ui.com/collections/grid.html for more info.